# Using Switch when there are less arguments than parameters

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a random integer based on a start and end value, however, if there is both not a start or end value, then the result will be 0. If there is either a start or end value, then the result will be 1.

I'm having trouble getting this code to output "0" when no arguments are passed.

```js
function randomInt(start, end){

 switch (!isNaN(start) && start !== null , !isNaN(end) && end !== null){ 
     
  case (true, false):
   console.log ("only one number generated: ")
      return 1
    break;
  case (false, false):
      console.log ("no start or end numbers generated: ")
   return 0
   break;
  case (true, true):
   console.log ("start and end numbers generate: ")
   return Math.round (Math.random() * (end-start) + start);
   break;  
 }
}

console.log (randomInt(4, 20))
console.log (randomInt(20, 4))
console.log (randomInt()) //this currently returns case (true, false)
console.log (randomInt(2))
```

Comment: If there occurs any problem you may find it on your browser's console

Comment: This is not how [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) works. While the syntax is valid, it doesn't do at all what you want to do. You can only `switch` on a **single value**. The code you have written is equivalent to simply removing everything that is before the commas in the `switch` and `case` conditions. You are "accidentally" using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) here.

Comment: Can't you use `if statement` ? in this case will be much better

Comment: I second what @FelixKling and @CalvinNunes said. You should use the `if statement` method instead of the `switch` method for this.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, I hadn't realized `switch` is meant for a single value only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comment by @Felix kling, your `switch` statement uses a valid syntax, but not for a switch, that allows a validation for a single value only. you should use it in an `if`.

If you are able to use `if statement`, the code below can be very useful for 
you. Take a look please.

```js
function randomInt(start, end){

 if ((start == null || isNaN(start)) && (end == null || isNaN(end))){
      return "no numbers are passed: "+ start + " and " + end;
  
  }else if (start == null || isNaN(start)) {  
     return "Just one number passed: "+ end;
     
  }else if (end == null || isNaN(end)){     
      return "Just one number passed: "+ start;
  } else {
    return "numbers ok: "+start+" and "+end;
  }
}

console.log (randomInt(4, 20))
console.log (randomInt(20, 4))
console.log (randomInt()) //this currently returns case (true, false)
console.log (randomInt(2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the boolean && to determine what should be returned and set parameters equal to false if they're not passed.

```
function randomInt(start = false, end = false) {
  let returnable; 

  start&&(returnable = 1, end)&&(returnable = 0);
  return returnable || Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start) + start);
}
```

```js
function randomInt(start = false, end = false) {
  let returnable; 
  
  start&&(returnable = 1, end)&&(returnable = 0);
  return returnable || Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start) + start);
}

console.log(randomInt(10, 20));
console.log(randomInt(10));
console.log(randomInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's code based on suggestions of Felix Cling, Calvin Nunes, and AndrewL.

```
function randomInt(start, end) {
  if (!start && !end) {
    return 0;
  } else if (!start || !end) {
    return 1;
  }

  return Math.round(Math.random() * (end - start) + start); 
}
```